# What is the meaning of being politically monochrome?

Tags: meaning

I recently read an article about how a state had become politically monochrome. I know what monochrome means. But I am unable to associate it with the phrase "Politically Monochrome"

Comment: "Politically monochrome" is far from being a common collocation. When I ran a Google search on it just now, I only obtained 68 hits, 22 of which all pointed to the same widely republished article from India titled "Why Gujarat has become politically monochrome is a mystery".

Comment: @ErikKowal : Yes, I was talking about that article.

Answer (score 2):

Monochrome literally means "one color".

In politics, it's very common to call different parties by an identifying color. For example in the United States "Red states" typically vote Republican while "Blue states" typically vote Democrat.

In a state where one party (or multiple similarly minded, and therefore similarly "colored" parties) consistently wins a super majority or other political solidification of power, you would consider it to be of one color, or monochrome.

Answer (score 1):

It may refer to the fact that in that specific country the main political party has won the majority of seats in a recent election , as a consequence   the country is now ruled by one single party. It refers also to countries that traditionally have been ruled by one large single [party](http://www.opendemocracy.net/article/institutions/china-s-political-colours-from-monochrome-to-palette).

> A dramatic but largely unacknowledged shift has recently taken place in how the past is understood in China. One way to think about this Chinese transformation is to see it as a sort of "colour revolution".

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is a lack of diversity in political opinion or allegiance. There is little contrast to be found, as if everything was the same colour.